# How can i compare dates with variables?

Tags: python, date

Please help i want to be able to do this better since im just learning python and i need to know this for school.

```
import datetime

TheDate = datetime.date.today()
ExpireDate = 0,0,0
Variable = datetime.date(ExpireDate)

ExpireDate = input("When does your card expire? (Year,Month,Day)" )

if Variable > TheDate:
     print("Your card has not expired")
else
     print("Your card has expired")
```

Comment: `<` and `>` are usable in comparing date objects, what issues are you having? Also, note that you ask for a 'real' `ExpireDate` from `input` _after_ creating `Variable`, so `Variable` is not going to change here.

Comment: Doesn't this give you an error? `Variable = datetime.date(ExpireDate)` ? Also, make sure you read the docs, specially [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime:~:text=the%20following%20constants%3A-,datetime.MINYEAR,-%C2%B6)

Comment: You're asking the user for input after `Variable` has already been created.  Presumably you want to do that _before_, so that `Variable` actually contains the entered date, instead of the default 0,0,0.

Comment: `else` should be `else:`

Comment: also, even with `Variable = date(0,0,0)`, which i'm not sure is possible, that means the `if` condition will never be true. since you can't have negative year/day I mean. or maybe I'm misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version i was able to put together:

```py
import datetime

TheDate = datetime.date.today()
ExpireDate = 1,1,1
Variable = datetime.date(*ExpireDate)


ExpireDate = input("When does your card expire? (Year,Month,Day)" )

if Variable > TheDate:
     print("Your card has not expired")
else:
     print("Your card has expired")
```

But also note that:

```py
ExpireDate = 1,1,1
Variable = datetime.date(*ExpireDate)
```

can just be replaced with:

```py
Variable = datetime.date.min
```

But **actually**, here is what I think you want to do:

```py
import datetime

TheDate = datetime.date.today()

ExpireDate = input("When does your card expire? (Year, Month, Day)  ")
Variable = datetime.date(*map(int, ExpireDate.replace(' ', '').split(',')))

if Variable > TheDate:
     print("Your card has not expired")
else:
     print("Your card has expired")
```

Here is a sample playthrough:

```
When does your card expire? (Year, Month, Day)  2022, 9, 2
Your card has not expired
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the input from the user before you can assign your `Variable` with the values that the user inputs.

Furthermore, you have to give `datetime.date()` the attributes it needs (year, month, date).

```
import datetime

TheDate = datetime.date.today()
ExpireDate = input("When does your card expire? (Year,Month,Day)" )
Variable = datetime.date(*[eval(x) for x in ExpireDate.split(',')])

if Variable > TheDate:
     print("Your card has not expired")
else:
     print("Your card has expired")
```

That `*[eval(x) for x in ExpireDate.split(',')]` bit can be explained as:

`ExpireDate.split(',')` splits the user input by comma into a list. The year, month, and date then exist in the newly created list `['2020','10','14']` as an example.

Those are strings, but we need integers for the `datetime.date()` method so we convert to integer using list comprehension and the `eval()` function: `[eval(x) for x in <the list>]`. The list will then look like `[2020,10,14]`, which is nice an integery.

Lastly we toss a `*` in front of that thing which tells python to take each value in the list and use it as a parameter in the `datetime.date()` function call.

Longer form:

```
import datetime

TheDate = datetime.date.today()
ExpireDate = input("When does your card expire? (Year,Month,Day)" )
ExpireDateList = ExpireDate.split(',')
ExpireDateIntList = []
for x in ExpireDateList:
    ExpireDateIntList.append(eval(x))
Variable = datetime.date(ExpireDateIntList[0],ExpireDateIntList[1],ExpireDateIntList[2])

if Variable > TheDate:
     print("Your card has not expired")
else:
     print("Your card has expired")
```

Comment: Thank you i am not very good at python since i just started learning it but this has helped me :)

Comment: Ultimately your date comparison (that you were asking about) was done correctly. It was just a matter of getting that user input from a string into a  proper `datetime`.

Comment: I added a longer "noob" version of all that split/eval/list-comprehension trickery so you could see what was happening with the shorthand code.